# add new wfe to an existing farm ssl cert question

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-server, ssl

I need to add a new WFE to an existing farm, do I need to purchase a new SSL certificate or can I reuse the existing certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to reuse the existing one. The cert you have should just be installed on the WFE and added to the bindings in IIS, and there you have it.